# Delete nodes in xml if they contain certain text using sed

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed

I have an xml that looks like following.

```
<rootNode>  
   <appender name="SERVER_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="C:/COM_FIND.log"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
      <param name="Append" value="true"/>
      <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB"/>
      <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>   
   <appender name="CAT_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="C:/COM_Now.log"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
      <param name="Append" value="true"/>
      <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB"/>
      <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender> 
    <appender name="SERVER_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
         <param name="File" value="C:/COM_A.log"/>
         <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
         <param name="Append" value="true"/>
         <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB"/>
         <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
         <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
         </layout>
   </appender>   
    <appender name="SERVER_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
         <param name="File" value="C:/COM_Find.log"/>
         <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
         <param name="Append" value="true"/>
         <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB"/>
         <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
         <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
         </layout>
   </appender>   
   <logger name="com.mycompany">
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SERVER_FILE"/>
    </logger>
</rootNode>
```

Yes.Its an excerpt from the log4j xml. What i basically want to do is remove all the appender tags/elements (from )that contain the word 'COM_Find.log' using the sed command.
What i have so far is this :-

```
sed -e '/<appender/,/<\/appender>/{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/COM_Find.log/d' file.xml
```

Which does a greedy search from the first appender to the last and deletes everything in between. I just want only those specific appender tags/elements(from ) to be removed.

The output should be:-

```
<rootNode>  
   <appender name="CAT_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="C:/COM_Now.log"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
      <param name="Append" value="true"/>
      <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB"/>
      <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender> 
    <appender name="SERVER_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
         <param name="File" value="C:/COM_A.log"/>
         <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
         <param name="Append" value="true"/>
         <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB"/>
         <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
         <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
         </layout>
   </appender>   
   <logger name="com.mycompany">
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SERVER_FILE"/>
    </logger>
</rootNode>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I am sure there are better tools for this in general..

Comment: remove just the appender tag or the whole block of appender?

Comment: the entire appender tag from <appender to </appender> that contain the search text.In this case the search text being 'COM_Find.log'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -ne '/rootNode/{ p; b }; /<appender /{ h; b }; /<logger /{ h; b }; H; /<\/logger>/{ x; p; b; }; /<\/appender>/{ x; /COM_Find[.]log/b; /COM_FIND[.]log/b; p }' file
```

Output:

```
<rootNode>  
   <appender name="CAT_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="C:/COM_Now.log"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
      <param name="Append" value="true"/>
      <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB"/>
      <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender> 
    <appender name="SERVER_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
         <param name="File" value="C:/COM_A.log"/>
         <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
         <param name="Append" value="true"/>
         <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB"/>
         <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
         <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
         </layout>
   </appender>   
   <logger name="com.mycompany">
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SERVER_FILE"/>
    </logger>
</rootNode>
```

Another for awk:

```
awk '{ p = 1 } /<appender /{ t = $0; while (getline > 0) { t = t ORS $0; if (/COM_FIND[.]log/ || /COM_Find[.]log/) p = 0; if (/<\/appender>/) break } $0 = t } p' file
```

Or GNU awk with `IGNORECASE`:

```
gawk -v IGNORECASE=1 '{ p = 1 } /<appender /{ t = $0; while (getline > 0) { t = t ORS $0; if (/COM_FIND[.]log/) p = 0; if (/<\/appender>/) break } $0 = t } p' file
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I have updated my answer with how the output should look. This one still has the first appender with the text COM_Find.log.

Comment: @user3824306 That's going to be more complex. I suggest using `XMLStarlet` instead.

Comment: thanks ..its working with the awk utility...one question..this command assumes the text to be found in next line after '<appender' begins if i m not wrong...can we have the search text in the line containing <appender tag?

Comment: @user3824306 It can only work with each element expanded as multiple lines. Condensed forms would need more difficult methods.

Comment: @user3824306 If possible it would be nice using a real XML parser on a language like Ruby. It should go easier and more precise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand do you want to remove the whole line?

if yes you can you `grep`:

```
grep -v "COM_Find.log" yourfile.xml > newfile.xml
```

Comment: the entire appender tag from <appender to </appender> that contain the search text.In this case the search text being 'COM_Find.log'