# Remove tag content from XML in linux console

Tags: xml, bash, jmeter, xmlstarlet

I'm stuck on one challenging tasks in manipulating Jmeter jtl report file. The basic idea is to remove from the jtl which is in XML format unwanted records(beanshell samplers and etc.) not needed for final report. So, I'm trying to find solution for removing those **sample** tags containing **ctrlSampler** string.

Tried with using the solution from this thread [Delete nodes in xml if they contain certain text using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989474/delete-nodes-in-xml-if-they-contain-certain-text-using-sed) but with no success

```
gawk -v IGNORECASE=1 '{ p = 1 } /<sample/{ t = $0; while (getline > 0) { t = t ORS $0; if (ctrlSampler) p = 0; if (/<\/sample>/) break } $0 = t } p' sourceJtl > targetJtl
```

Here is sample JTL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testResults version="1.2">
<sample t="15" lt="0" ts="1488375720156" s="true" lb="ctrlSampler - fWrite - reset noExecFailures variable" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="setUp prereqs 1-1" dt="text" by="0">
  <responseHeader class="java.lang.String"></responseHeader>
  <requestHeader class="java.lang.String"></requestHeader>
  <responseData class="java.lang.String"></responseData>
  <samplerData class="java.lang.String">        boolean  noExecFailures;
        vars.put(&quot;noExecFailures&quot;,&quot;true&quot;);

     f = new FileOutputStream(&quot;/opt/jmeter_test/execResult.property&quot;);
     p = new PrintStream(f);
     this.interpreter.setOut(p);
     print(&quot;noExecFailures=&quot; + vars.get(&quot;noExecFailures&quot;));
     f.close();
   </samplerData>
</sample>
<sample t="21" lt="0" ts="1488375720648" s="true" lb="[TP7][IMS][TEST PLAYER REQUESTS SUCCESS FLOW] 2-1::Notification::GetGlobalUrlsRequest" rc="200" rm="" tn="[TP7][IMS][TEST PLAYER REQUESTS SUCCESS FLOW] 2-1" dt="" by="598">
  <assertionResult>
    <name>Response Assertion - Verify success response</name>
    <failure>false</failure>
    <error>false</error>
  </assertionResult>
  <assertionResult>
    <name>Response Assertion - Verify response specific params</name>
    <failure>false</failure>
    <error>false</error>
  </assertionResult>
  <responseHeader class="java.lang.String"></responseHeader>
  <requestHeader class="java.lang.String"></requestHeader>
  <responseData class="java.lang.String"/>
  <samplerData class="java.lang.String">{
    &quot;headers&quot;: {
        &quot;messageId&quot;: &quot;5e5beb41-9cf0-4ef2-b678-7f47323b1b27&quot;
    },
    &quot;payload&quot;: {
        &quot;qualifier&quot;: &quot;com.playtech.ums.clientapi.notification.GetGlobalUrlsRequest&quot;,
        &quot;brandName&quot;: &quot;playtech32001&quot;,
        &quot;context&quot;: {
            &quot;sessionContext&quot;: {
                &quot;clientType&quot;: &quot;casino&quot;,
                &quot;clientPlatform&quot;: &quot;download&quot;
            },
            &quot;clientVersion&quot;: &quot;1&quot;,
            &quot;languageCode&quot;: &quot;EN&quot;
        },
        &quot;urlTypeList&quot;: [
            &quot;cashier&quot;,
            &quot;cashier_ext&quot;,
            &quot;myAccount&quot;
        ]
    }
}</samplerData>
</sample>
<sample t="7" lt="0" ts="1488375720706" s="false" lb="[TP7][IMS][TEST PLAYER REQUESTS SUCCESS FLOW] 2-1::Notification::GetGlobalUrlsRequest" rc="200" rm="" tn="[TP7][IMS][TEST PLAYER REQUESTS SUCCESS FLOW] 2-1" dt="" by="598">
  <assertionResult>
    <name>Response Assertion - Verify success response</name>
    <failure>false</failure>
    <error>false</error>
  </assertionResult>
  <assertionResult>
    <name>Response Assertion - Verify response specific params</name>
    <failure>true</failure>
    <error>false</error>
    <failureMessage>Test failed: text expected to contain /INJECT FAILIRE/</failureMessage>
  </assertionResult>
  <responseHeader class="java.lang.String"></responseHeader>
  <requestHeader class="java.lang.String"></requestHeader>
  <responseData class="java.lang.String"/>
  <samplerData class="java.lang.String">{
    &quot;headers&quot;: {
        &quot;messageId&quot;: &quot;edcf182a-82a4-4649-9e4b-b586e95fa26c&quot;
    },
    &quot;payload&quot;: {
        &quot;qualifier&quot;: &quot;com.playtech.ums.clientapi.notification.GetGlobalUrlsRequest&quot;,
        &quot;brandName&quot;: &quot;playtech32001&quot;,
        &quot;context&quot;: {
            &quot;sessionContext&quot;: {
                &quot;clientType&quot;: &quot;casino&quot;,
                &quot;clientPlatform&quot;: &quot;download&quot;
            },
            &quot;clientVersion&quot;: &quot;1&quot;,
            &quot;languageCode&quot;: &quot;EN&quot;
        },
        &quot;urlTypeList&quot;: [
            &quot;cashier&quot;,
            &quot;cashier_ext&quot;,
            &quot;myAccount&quot;
        ]
    }
}</samplerData>
</sample>

</testResults>
```

Result needed

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <testResults version="1.2">
    <sample t="21" lt="0" ts="1488375720648" s="true" lb="[TP7][IMS][TEST PLAYER REQUESTS SUCCESS FLOW] 2-1::Notification::GetGlobalUrlsRequest" rc="200" rm="" tn="[TP7][IMS][TEST PLAYER REQUESTS SUCCESS FLOW] 2-1" dt="" by="598">
      <assertionResult>
        <name>Response Assertion - Verify success response</name>
        <failure>false</failure>
        <error>false</error>
      </assertionResult>
      <assertionResult>
        <name>Response Assertion - Verify response specific params</name>
        <failure>false</failure>
        <error>false</error>
      </assertionResult>
      <responseHeader class="java.lang.String"></responseHeader>
      <requestHeader class="java.lang.String"></requestHeader>
      <responseData class="java.lang.String"/>
      <samplerData class="java.lang.String">{
        &quot;headers&quot;: {
            &quot;messageId&quot;: &quot;5e5beb41-9cf0-4ef2-b678-7f47323b1b27&quot;
        },
        &quot;payload&quot;: {
            &quot;qualifier&quot;: &quot;com.playtech.ums.clientapi.notification.GetGlobalUrlsRequest&quot;,
            &quot;brandName&quot;: &quot;playtech32001&quot;,
            &quot;context&quot;: {
                &quot;sessionContext&quot;: {
                    &quot;clientType&quot;: &quot;casino&quot;,
                    &quot;clientPlatform&quot;: &quot;download&quot;
                },
                &quot;clientVersion&quot;: &quot;1&quot;,
                &quot;languageCode&quot;: &quot;EN&quot;
            },
            &quot;urlTypeList&quot;: [
                &quot;cashier&quot;,
                &quot;cashier_ext&quot;,
                &quot;myAccount&quot;
            ]
        }
    }</samplerData>
    </sample>
    <sample t="7" lt="0" ts="1488375720706" s="false" lb="[TP7][IMS][TEST PLAYER REQUESTS SUCCESS FLOW] 2-1::Notification::GetGlobalUrlsRequest" rc="200" rm="" tn="[TP7][IMS][TEST PLAYER REQUESTS SUCCESS FLOW] 2-1" dt="" by="598">
      <assertionResult>
        <name>Response Assertion - Verify success response</name>
        <failure>false</failure>
        <error>false</error>
      </assertionResult>
      <assertionResult>
        <name>Response Assertion - Verify response specific params</name>
        <failure>true</failure>
        <error>false</error>
        <failureMessage>Test failed: text expected to contain /INJECT FAILIRE/</failureMessage>
      </assertionResult>
      <responseHeader class="java.lang.String"></responseHeader>
      <requestHeader class="java.lang.String"></requestHeader>
      <responseData class="java.lang.String"/>
      <samplerData class="java.lang.String">{
        &quot;headers&quot;: {
            &quot;messageId&quot;: &quot;edcf182a-82a4-4649-9e4b-b586e95fa26c&quot;
        },
        &quot;payload&quot;: {
            &quot;qualifier&quot;: &quot;com.playtech.ums.clientapi.notification.GetGlobalUrlsRequest&quot;,
            &quot;brandName&quot;: &quot;playtech32001&quot;,
            &quot;context&quot;: {
                &quot;sessionContext&quot;: {
                    &quot;clientType&quot;: &quot;casino&quot;,
                    &quot;clientPlatform&quot;: &quot;download&quot;
                },
                &quot;clientVersion&quot;: &quot;1&quot;,
                &quot;languageCode&quot;: &quot;EN&quot;
            },
            &quot;urlTypeList&quot;: [
                &quot;cashier&quot;,
                &quot;cashier_ext&quot;,
                &quot;myAccount&quot;
            ]
        }
    }</samplerData>
    </sample>

    </testResults>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this -

Testing -

```
sed -n '/sample/{/ctrlSampler/p}' f > f1

cat f1 ##### Here we have only one record. 
<sample t="15" lt="0" ts="1488375720156" s="true" lb="ctrlSampler - fWrite - reset noExecFailures variable" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="setUp prereqs 1-1" dt="text" by="0">
```

Delete the line which contain sample and ctrlSampler -

```
sed '/sample/{/ctrlSampler/d}' f > f2

diff f f2
3d2
< <sample t="15" lt="0" ts="1488375720156" s="true" lb="ctrlSampler - fWrite - reset noExecFailures variable" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="setUp prereqs 1-1" dt="text" by="0">
```

Comment: Thanks Vipin, 

actually I need to remove the sample tag if matches to string criteria ctrlSampler, not just the line

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, why cannot you just use [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/), it has `--exclude-label-regex` option therefore you will be able to filter the unwanted samplers.

The plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) or [manually](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-filterresults)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Filter Results Tool]

Upon successful installation you will find `FilterResults.sh` in JMeter's "bin" folder

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, 

please, advice how to use that, seems I'm not doing it right 

FilterResults.bat --output-file testFilterResutls.jtl --input-file ..\extras\JMeterClientAPI_regression_autotest.jtl --save-as-xml true --exclude-label-regex true --exclude-labels "ctrlSampler"

This passes but no records are removed in out file, I assume my exclude-labels regexp is not correct

Comment: You should be using a [Perl5-compatible regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), i.e. something like `".*ctrlSampler.*"`. See [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) chapter of JMeter User Manual and just in case [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) for more details.

Comment: Tried with using this regexp, checked in regex101.com but no luck 

lb="(ctrlSampler.*?)". Any suggestions?

Comment: How about the one I suggested above? `FilterResults.bat --output-file testFilterResutls.jtl --input-file ..\extras\JMeterClientAPI_regression_autotest.jtl --save-as-xml true --exclude-label-regex true --exclude-labels ".*ctrlSampler.*"`

Comment: the match is too wide, as far as I understand here we need the label only  Match count: 1
Match[1][0]="4" lt="0" ts="1488380834776" s="false" lb="ctrlSampler - fWrite - reset noExecFailures variable" rc="500" rm="org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval&#x9;Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``&#x9;boolean  noExecFailures;      &#x9;vars.put(&quot;noExecFailures&quot;,&quot;true&quot;);          f =  . . . &apos;&apos; : Object constructor" tn="setUp prereqs 1-1" dt="text" de="" by="0" ng="1" na="1" noExecFailures=""

Comment: with Synthesis Report plugin, which should be the GUI analog of FilterResults, the case is the same. By some reason regexp is not taken

Comment: Actually it worked at the end with flilter results plugin as you suggested. Case closed :)